# Как записать количество добавленных классов, если они при клике добавляются?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, смог добавлять цифру при клике в спан с классом parameter-count, а вот на уменьшение никак.

Вот прибавляет:

```
    var a = parameterCount.text();   
    parameterCount.html(1+parseInt(a));
```

А вот уменьшает (но не корректно работает):

```
    var b = parameterCount.text();   
    parameterCount.html(1-parseInt(b));
```

**Скрипт целиком:**

```js
var parameterCount = $('.parameter-count');

$(function() {

  $(".item").click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>,";

    $("#memory").html($("#memory").html().replace(text, ""));
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $("#memory").append(text);
    }

    if ($(".item.active").length) {
      $(".double-dots").show();


      var a = parameterCount.text();
      parameterCount.html(1 + parseInt(a));
    } else {
      $(".double-dots").hide();


      var b = parameterCount.text();
      parameterCount.html(1 - parseInt(b));
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title">Параметры (<span class="parameter-count">0</span>)</div>

<div class="filter-select">
  <div id="memory">
    <span>Встроенная память</span>
    <span class="double-dots" style="display: none">:</span>
  </div>

  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">256 GB</li>
    <li class="item">128 GB</li>
    <li class="item">64 GB</li>
    <li class="item">16 GB</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос, а при нескольких нажатиях параметр должен дублироваться?

Comment: Цель заставить счетчик считать количество выбранных параметров.

Когда нажал на параметр .item добавляется класс active, тогда прибавляется цифра в счетчике, а когда при повторном нажатии на этот же элемент с .active, то цифра уменьшается.

Comment: Но вы не ответили на мой вопрос, задам по другому, пользователь может выбрать только один параметр с значением, например, 256 GB ?

Comment: несколько может выбрать! а параметры дублироваться не должны, видать какая-то ошибка

Comment: Подправил пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю зачем вы так мучаетесь, вот простой пример, без каких-то сложных расчётов ))

```js
var parameterCount = $('.parameter-count');

$(function() {

  $(".item").click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>,";

    $("#memory").html($("#memory").html().replace(text, ""));
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $("#memory").append(text);
    }
   parameterCount.html($('.active').length); 
  });
  

  

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title">Параметры (<span class="parameter-count">0</span>)</div>

<div class="filter-select">
  <div id="memory">
    <span>Встроенная память</span>
    <span class="double-dots" style="display: none">:</span>
  </div>

  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">256 GB</li>
    <li class="item">128 GB</li>
    <li class="item">64 GB</li>
    <li class="item">16 GB</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```